# XHTML Compatibility - Storing HTML in a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I am stumped here.  I am working on switching my doctype to XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Since doing so, I've run into a validation issue.  I'm using Dynamic Drive's Ultimate Fade-in slideshow (found here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm) and feeding in all of my variables from a database.  To make that work, I have to populate some javascript variables.

**After I use the database to write out my javascript, I end up with the following:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var img1, img2, im3, img4, lnk1, lnk2, lnk3, lnk4, txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4;

img1 = "image1.jpg";
lnk1 = "/link1.php";
txt1 = "<font style='font-size: 14px;'><a href='/link1.php'>Article 1</a></font><br />Article 1 Content...";
img2 = "image2.jpg";
lnk2 = "/link2.php";
txt2 = "<font style='font-size: 14px;'><a href='/link2.php'>Article 2</a></font><br />Article 2 Content...";
img3 = "image3.jpg";
lnk3 = "/link3.php";
txt3 = "<font style='font-size: 14px;'><a href='/link3.php'>Article 3</a></font><br />Article 3 Content...";
img4 = "image4.jpg";
lnk4 = "/link4.php";
txt4 = "<font style='font-size: 14px;'><a href='/link4.php'>Article 4</a></font><br />Article 4 Content...";

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [600, 400], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
        [img1, lnk1, "", txt1],
        [img2, lnk2, "", txt2],
        [img3, lnk3, "", txt3],
        [img4, lnk4, "", txt4] // no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:5000, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "always",
    togglerid: ""
})
</script>
```

I get a number of validation errors all pointing to the html code I am storing in the txt[*x*] variables.

Samples:
Line 239, Column 39: document type does not allow element "font" here

```
txt1 = "<font style='font-size: 14px;'><a href='/link1.php…
```

Line 239, Column 126: document type does not allow element "br" here

```
…Article 1</a></font><br />Article 1 Content …
```

**Am I missing something obvious?  Or is HTML text in a javascript variable not an option when it comes to being XHTML compliant?**

Comment: i think your problem lies in the `<font>` tag itself. if i'm mistaken it has been depreciated. you should use css to style text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What validator are you using?

The w3c validator does not ignore what's inside the script tags, so if you have HTML in your script the validator will try to validate it as XHTML.

Put your script into a separate file.

Also, why are you worrying about validation if you are going to insert HTML4 tags via script?

Comment: I'm using [link](http://validator.w3.org/).  I'm not sure I can move the script onto a separate file because inside the script is where I am looping through query results to dynamically write out the values of my javascript variables.  As for the font tags, I forgoy they were deprecated and the validator didn't flag them, probably because I'm using Transitional.

Comment: @Micah - Have you considered generating the js on the server side? I don't know what web framework you're using but I'm sure there's a way to do it. On Django you can generate a js using a template.

Comment: The offending code is being generated server side.  I'm writing most of the script directly into the php page, all of the static content, but I have a database loop that is writing all of the values that populate the javascript variables on the server side.  When the W3C validator gets a look at it, all the server side stuff is done.  So I have my variables like `txt1 = "<a href='link1.php'>Title</a><br />Text` and the validator has an issue with the a tag and the br tag.  I did try splitting it off onto a .js, but not sure if you run php code to loop through my query results in a .js

Comment: the validador doesn't like tags embeded on your script.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can generate a dynamic .js with php

Comment: I will look into writing out a dynamic .js - If I can get it writing out to a separate file as you suggested, then it shouldn't get hit by the validator.  Thanks for sticking with this one!

Answer (score 0):

`font` is deprecated in HTML 4 Strict and XHTML. Use the proper semantic element and style it, which would be `a` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Okay, to test that out I removed the <font> tags.  So the errors have changed.  Problem seems to be it doesn't like any of my HTML tags.  It doesn't seem to like my <a> tags or <br /> either.

Comment: @Micah - Do as I said in my answer. Put your script in a separate file.